# Server not pinging even after setting gateway and ip

Tags: linux, ping, trace

I am configuring an Icinga monitoring server. I am entirely new to Linux, so configuring after googling each and every bit. I have configured ip address, subnet mask and default gateway correctly. "ifconfig" and "route -n" shows me the correct one (what I have given to configure the server). Someone has already configured another server, so I am referring that too while configuring.

After setting the default gateway, I cant ping to that gateway ip though I can ping to the loopback address and to the local server ip. I have referred the already configured server and found that both server uses same gateway..The already configured server can ping this gateway, but not mine.

What will be the issue?? Can someone please help me on this,since my work is on hold now??

Comment: Can the working machine ping the non-working machine?

Comment: nope...but can ping the same gateway..

Comment: If I remember correctly, the default install of CentOS 6 doesn't bring up the interface on boot. Take a look at /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 (hoping that's the name of your interface) and see if ONBOOT=yes. You can also run ifup eth0 (again hoping that's the name of your interface) as a test.

Comment: In the question you said you CANNOT ping the gateway, but the comment says you CAN. Please explain

Comment: @DavidHoude: I meant I can't ping to the gateway from non working machine but can ping to the same gateway from working machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the root cause.. This might be a basic issue... But posting if in case helps this anyone..

My hostname (or FQDN) and IP was not added in **/etc/hosts** file. And it worked!!!